# Batch Script : File Size as output on Different Server

Tags: batch-file

sample BAT Script

```
set host=%COMPUTERNAME%
for %I in ("D:\App\Config - %date:/=-% *.zip") do @echo %host% Confi FileSize - %~zI >>"\\hostname\d$\Output\Output %date:/=-%.txt"
```

ERROR :

The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid:

> %~zI >>"\hostname\d$\Output\Output %date:/=-%.txt"

Comment: if you are running in batch script the `%` sign in `for` subtitution variables must be doubled `%%I` `%%~zI` etc

Comment: @elzooilogico oh that is there in Scipt... I forgot when I pasted it here.

Also, now using for %%I instead of for %I

Comment: Perfect @elzooilogico using %%~zI helped me... Thanks a lot :-)